# Getting Error when to save image bitmap A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapimage

My code is given below what i am trying to do is, getting an image from project folder and then adding some text on the image and then save it to the same folder.

```
string firstText = "Hello";
string secondText = "World";

PointF firstLocation = new PointF(10f, 10f);
PointF secondLocation = new PointF(10f, 50f);
var imageFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + "a.png");

Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);//load the image file

using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    using (Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", 10))
    {
        graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, firstLocation);
        graphics.DrawString(secondText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, secondLocation);
    }
}

bitmap.Save(imageFilePath);//save the image file
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I just did this and its working   bitmap.Save(imageFilePath+".jpg");//save the image file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what happen is you are trying to overwrite an image file that are currently opened:

`Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);//load the image file`

What you can do is make a separate instance of the `bitmap`, close the source, before saving it to the same file.

Here's a code that you can refer to:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);
Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, bitmap.PixelFormat); //Create temporary bitmap
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(temp))
{
    using (Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", 10))
    {
        //Copy source image first
        graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, temp.Width, temp.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, firstLocation);
        graphics.DrawString(secondText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, secondLocation);
    }
}
bitmap.Dispose(); //Dispose your source image
temp.Save(imageFilePath);//save the image file
temp.Dispose(); //Dispose temp after saving
```

Comment: Right...see the docs for [Image.FromFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx): _The file remains locked until the Image is disposed._  So you need to dispose of the instance to release the file before you attempt to overwrite it.

Comment: Be aware that adding `.jpg` will change the filename of your target file, hence creating a new one on the file system, `a.png` now becomes `a.png.jpg`. This might not be the behavior that you want.